# Login as root in Debian UI

Tags: linux, permissions, debian

I have built a web application in Windows which uploads and then deletes a file. When I deployed my `war` file in Debian Linux to Tomcat server, it allows me to upload the file and save it in the file system, but when I am trying to delete that file, it doesn't work because of the file's permissions.

I want to login as a root user in Debian UI. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can launch Nautilus using `gksudo` and manage the filesystem if you are only interested in files or folders.

As a normal user, just press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and enter `gksudo nautilus`.

It is advised not to login as as root into a Linux box. Use `sudo` and if you want to act as root, use `su`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the UI-manager (e.g. GDM/KDM/XDM) you need to tell them (for KDM it's /etc/kdm/kdmrc) that root-logins are allowed.

An alternative (and recommanded way) is to create a normal user to login and then use sudo to run root-commands.